# Issue to type text in a webpage loaded in a UIWebView using UI Testing in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I'm struggling to type text in a UIWebView that is embedded in a native UIViewController. I loaded google in the web view, and I'm simply trying to enter "Hello". Recording suggests using app.typeText("Hello") but I keep getting the error

UI Testing Failure - Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus.

Any suggestions?

Project showing the issue, please test your possible answer by checking out this source by running from Terminal: 
`git clone git@bitbucket.org:Smaljaars/uitestingexample.git`

**UPDATE** I found a workaround for typing text in a text field inside a web view:

```
func testWorkAroundForProblem() {

    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.otherElements["Zoek"].tap() //this is language dependent! (no accessibility identifiers within webview)

    // UGLY WORKAROUND FOR THE PROBLEM
    let textToType = "XCTest slow search Google"
    for character in textToType.characters {
        if character == " " {
            app.descendants(matching: .any)["space"].tap()
            continue
        }
        app.descendants(matching: .any)[character.description.lowercased()].tap()
    }

    app.webViews.buttons["Google zoeken"].tap() //this is language dependent! (no accessibility identifiers within webview)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First make sure the search box has focused. The Accessibility Inspector shows that you should be able to access it via "Search". Oddly, Google marks the field as a combo box.

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.comboBoxes["Search"].tap()
app.typeText("Hello")
```

[image: Accessibility Inspector for Google.com]

Comment: It does not work. This is the accessibility on when checking google on Safari, but embedded in the app the Accessibility Inspector does not identify the text box as a combo box, but as a AXGenericElement. I updated the question with the Accessibility Inspector output when viewing the google search bar from within a UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

On the iOS Simulator menu, go to the Hardware dropdown and toggle the 'Connect Hardware Keyboard' setting.

This sometimes prevents UI tests from typing in text boxes.

Comment: This does not work in this case, but it's true this can fix problems with entering text in a text field